# Basic populating of a select form

Tags: php, html, mysql

Basically trying to populate a drop-down select bar from a table called "Cars" with data in the "VIN" column. It's giving me a blank.

```
<form>
    <label>VIN:</label>
    <select name="formVIN">
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT VIN FROM Cars";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['VIN'] . "'>" . $row['VIN'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
</form>
```

I would like to take it a step further by displaying ONLY the VIN's of those cars not sold. I have a column in the table "Cars" that has either a 'Y' or 'N' if sold. So I would like it to show only the ones with 'N' as well.

Comment: For each iteration I see you are echoing a closing select tag. For your second question I'd look up 'where' in SQL

Comment: do you get values on that $row['VIN'], or just your first value on the select gets blank?

Comment: I see what you mean, I thought it would only put the closing select tag once there were no more results, thus the WHILE being used. It's giving me complete blank, not even the first record is being pulled up. I am uber noob so please excuse my "code"

Comment: I took the closing select tag off the php code and put it just before the closing form tag and after the closing php tag and still didn't work. I don't think it was echoing it for each iteration, it was outside of the { code to be executed } brackets.

Comment: That second part of it was totally a dumb question, I never thought of just adding the WHERE VSOLD='N' to the SQL. I still can't figure the first part though.

Comment: Is `$row['VIN']` blank, or is the whole page blank?  Also, try running `print_r($row);`  the line after the start of the while loop. (this will print the whole content of the array on the screen) Perhaps you're getting a different result than you expect.

Comment: While this particular query isn't vulnerable, you should educate yourself about sql injection.  Also, the mysql php extension is deprecated and you should be using myslqi instead.

Comment: Check the source in the browser. is it really blank or is it just badly formed html?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT VIN FROM Cars WHERE VSold='N'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=" . $row["VIN"] . ">" . $row["VIN"] . "</option>";
}
} else {
echo "<option value=''>ALL SOLD</option>";
}
```

Figured I'd try a different approach, and while the WHILE did make sense, this isn't too bad either. I'm still learning, a lot, and some of your comments helped me see things from a different perspective. I tried a lot of different options, thank you all.